# Multiple pgpool-II on same Postgres instances

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

Can you run multiple instances of pgpool-II on same Postgres databases? My idea that I want to have really redundancy, so if pgpool-II went down, I can easily access another one without any downtime, data loss as databases will still be running.

Do you know can you do this is case:

1) One pgpool-II is active and another is in standby mode?
2) Both pgpool-II are active (SQL query can come to any of them).

Databases are replicated (same data across them). Will there we conflicts at replication in case of multiple pgpools?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have one active and one passive pgpool. If both will be active they might choose different masters in case of a db failover and cause a mess. pgpool is ready for this architecture with its [watchdog module](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/pgpool-II-3.2.0/wd-en.html).